# Angular 5 HTTPclient json error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular5

I am trying to import data from json file in my Angular 5 ionic project, but I cant because I am getting error : 
**TS2339: property results does not exist on type 'Object'** which is in home.ts (2 of them)

Provider : **people.ts**

```
  getPeople() {
    return this.http.get('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cghlMAGJvm?indent=10')
  }
}
```

**home.ts**

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public service: People)
  {
    this.service.getPeople()

      .subscribe(
        data => this.people = data.results
      )
  }

  toggleReorder(){
    this.shouldReorder = !this.shouldReorder
  }
doRefresh(e){
this.service.getPeople()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.people.unshift(...data.results),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => e.complete()
  )
}
}
```

As I saw in angular/http guide there should be like that :

```
showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    .subscribe(data => this.config = {
        heroesUrl: data['heroesUrl'],
        textfile:  data['textfile']
    });
}
```

**But I want to copy all the data not only few parts. What is the right way of doing it ?**

Comment: also getting error in browser : 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.service.getPeople(...).subscribe is not a function
TypeError: this.service.getPeople(...).subscribe is not a function

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Also, I'd suggest you read https://angular.io/guide/http.

Comment: I copied only the parts where the 'results' is. The word 'results' comes twice and wrote another error which I see on the browsers. Both are in my code. No more, no less. And yes I saw the http guide of angular, did everything right.

Comment: You haven't done everything right, you haven't *typed* anything. Hence the compiler's complaint.

Comment: Could you please tell me what I have to do ?

Comment: In Angular 5 by default `http.get()` return `data`. It's object from response body so you can't use `data.result` if your response doesn't has `result` property.

Answer (score 1):

On your `people.ts` add an import for the map operator.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


getPeople() {
    return this.http.get('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cghlMAGJvm?indent=10').map(res => res.json());
}
```

The response given from http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cghlMAGJvm?indent=10 is already the result, so no need to add `data.results`, that property doesn't exist on the response.

```
this.service.getPeople().subscribe( data => {
    this.people = data
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it really worked, but there is one more problem --> 

it works with : http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cghlMAGJvm?indent=2 this json , but dont works with this I need : 
https://randomuser.me/api/?results=300 , why ?

Comment: error from browser : 
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: Fixed everything , thnx you again.